# Viewing the profile of a person you invited?

Tags: support, jobs

On SO careers, it lets you view all the people you've invited and whether they accepted and published their profile. I was curious and wanted to take a peek at what they put on their profile. Is there any way to get their name to become a link to their Careers profile once they've published it? At least for the invitations that you've personally sent out (maybe not for the ones invited via link).

It's like inviting someone to a party and then not being able to see or talk to them once they show up.

Comment: I suspect there would be some real data-protection issues making their data available to you just because you invited them... you could just ask them? (IIRC they can give you a time-limited private URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to make the profile public and I believe also searchable for employers - this last bit is the key as it opens the profile to the public, including you.

Once that is done, the `yes` under the "published" column in the invites page will become a link to the profile.